# How do I replace the string exactly in dataset

Tags: r

I have this vector

```
x<- c("Store Leader", "Produce Lead", "Stock Lead", "Assitance Leader")
```

I want to replace every job title with the word Lead with just "Lead"

I have been trying this without success

```
x2 <- gsub("\\<Lead\\>","Lead",x, ignore.case = TRUE)
```

The result should look like this: x<- c("Lead", "Store Leader", "Lead", "PH Leader")

Thanks

Comment: Try `gsub("\\b(Lead)\\S+", "\\1", x, ignore.case = TRUE)#[1] "Store Lead"     "Produce Lead"   "Stock Lead"     "Assitance Lead"`

Comment: Since `\\<` and `\\>` are for word-boundaries (technically *"empty string at the beginning and end of a word"*), using `\\<Lead\\>` would match a singleton `Lead` and then replace it with ... `Lead`.

Comment: When you say you want to replace the job title with just "Lead", does this mean that your desired output is `"Lead"` for all four in your `x`? (That is, not `"Store Lead"`, right?)

Comment: If yes, then I'd think `sub(".*\\bLead.*", "Lead", x, ignore.case=TRUE)` might be enough.

Comment: Or: `x[grep("Lead", x, ignore.case = TRUE)] <- "Lead"`

Comment: Sorry, It doesn't work but thanks

Comment: I need to substitute only titles with the job lead, and leave leaders as they are. The code we are working with is changing everything to "lead" ty

Comment: The result should look like this: x<- c("Lead", "Store Leader", "Lead", "PH Leader")

Answer (score 0):

This works the way you want, since it seems "Lead" will always occur at the end of the string.

```
x<- c("Store Leader", "Produce Lead", "Stock Lead", "Assitance Leader")

x2 <- sub(".*Lead$", "Lead", x, ignore.case = TRUE)

str(x2)
```

chr [1:4] "Store Leader" "Lead" "Lead" "Assitance Leader"